# How to prime angular $http cache ($cacheFactory) with static JSON content?

Tags: json, angularjs, caching

My goal is to get `$http` to work on my local filesystem by caching some static JSON objects in a `$cacheFactory`. I wish to avoid network requests entirely and use only cached content.

The issue is that `$http` is making server requests regardless of the existence of cached content. My code is as follows.

**Cache Factory**

```
myApp.factory('jsonCache', function($cacheFactory){
  // create new cache object
  // (tried $cacheFactory.get('$http') as well, but same result)
  var cache = $cacheFactory('jsonCache');

  // put static value in cache
  cache.put('/json/file1.json', {"key":"value"});

  return cache;
});
```

**Factory using $http**

```
myApp.factory('AjaxFactory', function($http, jsonCache){

  console.log(jsonCache.info()); // {id: 'jsonCache', size: 1}

  // this will make a request to "http://localhost/json/file1.json"
  // even though there is an entry for that URL in the cache object
  $http.get('/json/file1.json', {cache: jsonCache}).success(/* ... */);

  return { /* ... */ };
});
```

At this point I'm thinking it may be the format of the data I'm using in `cache.put()`, but unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to get it working as desired on this plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/x1nfjwEoJOxzZN5PUyrX?p=preview

```
angular.module("myApp", [])

.factory('jsonCache', function($cacheFactory) {
  // create new cache object
  // (tried $cacheFactory.get('$http') as well, but same result)
  var cache = $cacheFactory('jsonCache');

  // put static value in cache
  cache.put('file1.json', {
    "key": "From Cache Factory"
  });

  return cache;
})

.factory('jsonFactory', function($http, jsonCache) {

  var get = function(url) {
    return $http.get(url, {
      cache: jsonCache
    });
  };

  return {
    get: get
  };

})

.controller("Ctrl", function($scope, jsonFactory, jsonCache) {
  $scope.cacheInfo = jsonCache.info();

  jsonFactory.get('file1.json').success(function(res) {
    $scope.json = res;
  });
});
```

I think the issue with my original code was the result of one of the many 3rd party module dependencies. (doh!)

My workaround for the code as it was, was the following:

```
myApp.factory('jsonFactory', function($http, $q, jsonCache){
  var get = function(url){
    var data = jsonCache.get(url);

    // if data exists in cache, wrap in promise and return
    // or do regular $http get
    if(data){
      return $q(function(resolve, reject){ resolve(data); });
    } else {
      return $http.get(url);
    }
  };

  return {
    get: get
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see demo code below, commends should help you a bit

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  //
  // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");
  //
  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider.state('state1', {
      url: "/state1",
      template: "<h1>State1 </h1> <pre>{{cache | json}}</pre>",
      controller: 'state1Ctrl'
    })
    .state('state2', {
      url: "/state2",
      template: "<h1>State2 </h1><pre>{{cache | json}}</pre>",
      controller: 'state2Ctrl'
    });

});


app.controller('state1Ctrl', function($scope, myCache) {

  var cache = myCache.cache.get('jsonCache');



  //check if cached data exist

  if (cache) {

    //use cached data
    $scope.cache = myCache.cache.get('jsonCache');

    //if not update cache
  } else {
    myCache.update().success(function(data) {

      //set cache
      myCache.cache.put('jsonCache', data.info);

      console.log(myCache.cache.info());


      //get  cached data
      $scope.cache = myCache.cache.get('jsonCache');

    }).error(function() {

      console.log("error");
    });
  }

});
app.controller('state2Ctrl', function($scope, myCache) {
  var cache = myCache.cache.get('jsonCache');


  if (cache) {
    $scope.cache = myCache.cache.get('jsonCache');

  } else {
    myCache.update().success(function(data) {

      myCache.cache.put('jsonCache', data.info);

      console.log(myCache.cache.info());

      $scope.cache = myCache.cache.get('jsonCache');

    }).error(function() {

      console.log("error");
    });
  }

});
app.factory('myCache', function($cacheFactory, $http) {
  // create new cache object

  var cache = $cacheFactory('jsonCache');

  // put static value in cache
  function update() {
    alert("update")
    return $http.get("https://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=kaizers+orchestra");
  }
  return {
    cache: cache,
    update: update
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="
               https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.13/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JS Bin</title>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ui-view></div>
  <!-- We'll also add some navigation: -->
  <a ui-sref="state1">State 1</a>
  <a ui-sref="state2">State 2</a>
</body>
```

Comment: So you basically **have** to do an `if`. It looks like `$http` won't read from the cache directly; at least not on the first get.

Comment: @SteamDev first you have to populate cache with data, and after that you can use cached data instead making another call to server

Comment: Thats what I'm doing on this line in my cache factory `cache.put('/json/file1.json', {"key":"value"});`, but `$http` still makes a request for file1.json. Perhaps I'll create a plunk to better illustrate the issue.